# What are the results of doing meththa meditation?

Tags: sutras, suttas, meditation

What are the results of doing meththa meditation?

can someone point out some reference from "suttas" (A translation of a sutta)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many good returns of Meththa to a practitioner.If you look at "Meththanisansa sutta" Lord Buddha had spoken of all of those in one teaching.Here's the english translation of Meththanisansa sutta

---

### Meththanisansa sutta

I heard this way.....

Once when Lord Buddha was residing in Jethavana Monastery of noble anepidu Lord Buddha started a conversation saying fortune ate monks, The monks replied saying "yes,Fortunate one".Lord Buddha then went on to teach this.

Fortunate monks, one should expect 11 returns from a "**Meththa Samadhi**" which has been

Frequently practiced

Practiced like a vehicle/ship

That has been a basic goal of the mind

Which has been started well

And which has been established well in the mind.

What are these 11 returns?

- Sleeping without discomfort
- waking up without discomfort
- Not seeing sinister dreams
- Others become friendly
- **Non-human beings** become friendly
- Receives protection from "Devas"
- Becomes free from any harm that comes from fire,wepons or poison
- Reaches "Samadhi" Faster
- Face/Appearance becomes pleasant
- **Die with proper consciousness**
- If this person fail to reach the goals of the path he/she will have the next life among **Brahmas**

One should expect these 11 returns from a "**Meththa Samadhi**" which has been

*Frequently practiced*

*Practiced like a vehicle/ship*

*That has been a basic goal of the mind*

*Which has been started well*

*And which has been established well in the mind.*

Lord Buddha taught this and the "Sangha**" accepted it happily.

May the power of truth in these words bring comfort to all

---

**Explanation of marked words above.**

*Meththa Samadhi** -*

*Samadhi is a state of mind in which the chaotic state of the mind has been stopped by a meditation. Mettha samadhi is reaching it with Meththa meditation*

*Non-human beings** -*

*Non-Human beings are Brahmas,Devas,Animals,Asuras and beings in lower realms*

*Die with proper consciousness** -*

*This means when the person dies he/she will not be dying with fear,anger,hate,greed or any other corrupting state of mind.The person will die with the knowledge of death and will be conscious enough to revisit the learning of dhamma*

*Brahmas** -*

*Brahmas are at the peak of life.They are even above the "Devas" and they are actually the highest that any normal being can reach without the help of dhamma.Birth in this realm happens only to beings with "Samadhi".They hold the highest life expectancy of all beings (Unfortunately our number system will not have a number to match it).

*Sangha** -*

*The holy monks.*

Comment: A translation from Access to Insight: [Metta (Mettanisamsa) Sutta (AN 11.16)](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/an/an11/an11.016.piya.html)

Comment: Wonderful answer and the canonical resource for such an inquiry!

Comment: Thanks @ChrisW  for mentioning the International name of the sutta.What i mentioned was our local name.